# Passing variable length list as an argument to threaded function

Tags: python, list, parameter-passing, python-multithreading

I'm trying to pass a list as an argument to a threaded function. This list can vary in it's length, but I can't figure out how to do it. Below is the code I'm using. For now, I just want to be able to get the list into the threaded function and print it on-screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import Queue as queue


def generateRange(starting_chars=(*args)):
    print str(starting_chars)


for i in range(32,126):
    q = queue.Queue()
    theArgs = [i,32,32]
    threads = [ threading.Thread(target=generateRange,args=theArgs) ]
    # generateRange([i,32,32]) 
    for th in threads:
        th.daemon = True
        th.start()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
    File "./test.py", line 6
    def generateRange(starting_chars=(*args)):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the syntax to this, otherwise `args` will not be defined:

```
def generateRange(*starting_chars):
    print str(starting_chars)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you specifically want the argument to be named 'starting_chars' but:

```
def generateRange(*starting_chars):
    print str(starting_chars)
```

or

```
def generateRange(*args):
    print str(args)
```

should work fine